# "Tuple index out of range" error in mlflow pytorch

Tags: pytorch, mlflow

I am running the first example of [this](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pytorch.html) page(training mnist using mlflow pytorch). Why does it give tuple index out of range?

[image]

Comment: what MLflow version?

Comment: Please paste the `code` and any errors as text, not an image.

Comment: hey Alex,the version is 1.18.0